# Custom slider in react, Swiping images effecting all product images when next arrow btn pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, customization, slide

I created function to swipe selected product image inside slide with left and right arrow btns. but when clicked it is swiping every item image not single one. i could not use newSlideArray variable outside of the function. can anyone explain me how to swipe single item image in slide ?

Here is my source code:

```
class ViewCart extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0
    }
  nextSlide =(item)=> {
    let newSlideArray = [];
    item.gallery.map(img => newSlideArray.push(img))
    if(this.state.index === (newSlideArray.length - 1)){
      this.setState({
        index: 0
      })
    }else{
      this.setState({
        index: this.state.index + 1
      })
    } 
  } 
render() {
    return (
        {this.props.cart.map((item, index) => (
          <div>
              <div className={styles.slide}>
                <div className={styles.leftArrow} onClick={()=> {this.previousSlide(item)}}>&#8592; 
                <div className={styles.rightArrow} onClick={()=> {this.nextSlide(item)}}>&#8594;
                <img src={item.gallery[this.state.index]} alt="" />
              </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here is. When right arrow pressed it is swiping every product image to the right not single one.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw0ME.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep the picture index for each `item`. I'm using functional style for simplicity.

```
const [indexes, setIndexes] = useState({});
```

Asuming the item has an `id`:

```
const nextSlide = (item) => {
  const curIndex = indexes[item.id] || 0;
  const newIndex = curIndex === item.gallery.length - 1 ? 0 : curIndex + 1;
  setIndexes({ ...indexes, [item.id]: newIndex });
};
```

And then:

```
<img src={item.gallery[indexes[item.id] || 0]} alt="" />
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bash-91l1rb?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that all the cards shares the same state which cause when a single card's state changes all other cards will be affected. try separate them by making your state holds an index for each card inside the `ViewCart` and when you click on the next or prev buttons pass to the function that card's index to update his state separately.

Something like this:

```js
class ViewCart extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = this.props.cart.map(()=>({index:0}))
  nextSlide =(item,index)=> {
    const galleryLen = item.gallery.length
    if(this.state[index].index === (galleryLen - 1)){
      const arr = [...this.state]
      arr[index] = {index: 0}
      this.setState(arr)
    }else{
      const arr = [...this.state]
      arr[index] = {index: this.state[index]+1}
      this.setState(arr)
      this.setState(arr)
    } 
  } 
render() {
    return (
        {this.props.cart.map((item, i) => (
          <div>
              <div className={styles.slide}>
                <div className={styles.leftArrow} onClick={()=> {this.previousSlide(item,i)}}>&#8592; 
                <div className={styles.rightArrow} onClick={()=> {this.nextSlide(item,i)}}>&#8594;
                <img src={item.gallery[this.state[i].index]} alt="" />
              </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
  }
```